# Spark SQL cannot use current date in subquery

Tags: sql, azure, apache-spark

I have a process which posts logs into a Spark database:

[image: Image of SQL querying table]

I'm trying to make the SQL more dynamic by supplying the current date in the query like so, but when I do it returns 0:

[image: image of SQL to return results]

Running the subquery on its own works:
[image: Subquery working on its own]

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with the query is that you are adding single quotes around the pattern generated by the subquery. This means that the  `like`  operator will only match rows where the  `batch_insert_Date`  column starts with a single quote, followed by the date prefix generated by the subquery. To fix this issue, you can remove the single quotes from the pattern generated by the subquery. Here's an example of how you can modify the query to do this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE batch_insert_Date LIKE
(SELECT CONCAT(cast(date_format(current_date(),'yyyyMMdd') as string), '%') AS date_col)
```

In this modified query, the  `CONCAT()`  function is used to concatenate the date prefix generated by the subquery with the  `%`  wildcard character, which matches any number of characters. The  `LIKE`  operator is then used to match the  `batch_insert_Date`  column with the pattern generated by the subquery.

This query should return all rows from  the table  where the  `batch_insert_Date`  column starts with the current date in the  `yyyyMMdd`  format.

[image]

Comment: That's superb! Worked a treat!!! Thank you very much for the detailed explanation...